# drawing a triangle on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am having trouble drawing a triangle on a canvas. Triangle: equilateral triangle with 2 points on the x-axis. So what I was thinking: I start in the bottom right corner, move up to the next point, and then move to the last point in the lower left. Here is what I have:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
     function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if (canvas.getContext) {
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       
       var sWidth = screen.width;
       var sHeight = screen.height;
          var path=new Path2D();
          path.moveTo((sWidth/2)+50,sHeight/2);
          path.lineTo((sWidth/2),(sHeight/2)-50);
          path.lineTo((sWidth/2)-50,sHeight/2);
          ctx.fill(path);
        }
       }
    
    
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="draw();">
     <div align = "center">
      <canvas id = "canvas">
    
      </canvas>
    
     </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Nothing gets drawn. I read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes, but I'm not sure what I messed up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to give a size to your canvas. Either with CSS, HTML or in JavaScript

Here is a snippet that works :

```js
 function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var sWidth = canvas.width;
            var sHeight = canvas.height;
            var path=new Path2D();
            path.moveTo((sWidth/2)+50,sHeight/2);
            path.lineTo((sWidth/2),(sHeight/2)-50);
            path.lineTo((sWidth/2)-50,sHeight/2);
            ctx.fill(path);
        }
    }

draw();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "UTF-8">

<style>canvas { width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; }</style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas">

  </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```